# How to link extern librarys in the llvm IR representation

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Hey i use clang++ to convert the program in IR representation with the command:

clang++ -S -emit-llvm program.cpp

Then i search in this .ll file with llvm pass to certain properties. Is there a possibility to get extern librarys in this representation?
Normally i can only see the names from the calling functions.

Example:

```
#include "stdio.h"

 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("hi");
    return 0;
 }
```

IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'main.cpp'
 target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
 target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

 @.str = private unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"hi\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: norecurse uwtable
  define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) #0 {
  entry:
   %retval = alloca i32, align 4
   %argc.addr = alloca i32, align 4
   %argv.addr = alloca i8**, align 8
   store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
   store i32 %argc, i32* %argc.addr, align 4
   store i8** %argv, i8*** %argv.addr, align 8
   %call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
   ret i32 0
     }

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1

attributes #0 = { norecurse uwtable "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 3.8.1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)"}
```

In this case, I can only see the printf function. Is there a way to get "stdio.h" in the representation?

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted but the short answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

stdio.h contains only the *declaration* of printf, not the definition. The compiler does not see it when it emit the LLVM IR.

Technically you can get the full program in IR using LTO (including static archive libraries). However usually the libc isn't built for LTO and you won't see the body of printf anyway.

For embedded development (firmware...), the LTO phase usually sees the full program.